# How to change the toolbar button's Bitmap in win32?

Tags: c++, winapi, hwnd, toolbars, hbitmap

I have created a toolbar with some controls on it using ReBar within a window. Can anyone please tell me,

1. How to get the HWND of a **buttons/combobox/etc** (not normal buttons in a window) if I know (only) the Id of it ?
2. How to obtain the HBITMAP if I know the id of the resource ?
3. How to set the bitmap to the controller ?

   SendDlgItemMessageW(hWnd,  nId,  BM_SETIMAGE,  IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBitmap);

This isn't working for toolbars, isn't it ? I couldn't find a way to do it, please help me. Thank you...

Regards

EDIT:
Anyone please ? :(

EDIT:
Ok. it seems everyone is busy these days. :( Btw, is it a wrong question ?

Comment: What do you mean by controller? a rebar band?

Comment: Hey! Anything in a rebar such as Button, Combobox, etc. (I didn't have any other word to describe it). Thanks.

Comment: I thought that a rebar control contains one or more rebar bands, and that a rebar band could only contain one control. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774373(VS.85).aspx. Could you please elaborate on what you mean in the lanuage of this MSDN article?

Comment: Hey! I just know that to create the toolbar, it used rebar CONCEPT (Actually I don't know further details). So, I have ids for every buttons in toolbar, HWND for rebar and toolbar window. Now I have to change the bitmap of a button (in the toolbar) using this knowledge. Can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could download [ControlSpy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773165(VS.85).aspx) and try it in there to get a feel for it.
I checked the Rebar and saw that RB_SETBANDINFO (under *Messages*) could be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[GetDlgItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645481(VS.85).aspx) will work just as well with a Rebar as it does with a Dialog.

> You can use the GetDlgItem function with any parent-child window pair, not just with dialog boxes. As long as the hDlg parameter specifies a parent window and the child window has a unique identifier (as specified by the hMenu parameter in the CreateWindow or CreateWindowEx function that created the child window), GetDlgItem returns a valid handle to the child window.

You can use LoadImage to load a bitmap from a resource and return the HBITMAP.

Finally, `SendMessage(hWndButton, BM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM) IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM) hBitmap);`